# Optimizing C code size without polymorphism

Tags: c

I've read on this site and somewhere else about polymorphism in C, and most commentators discourage from doing this, or advice to use C++ instead. I have structs and routines very similar to each other that differ only by the member and argument type. Here is the code:

h file:

```
typedef struct {
  double *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} dArray;
void init_dArray(dArray *a, size_t initialSize);
void insert_dArray(dArray *a, double element); 

typedef struct {
  char** array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} sArray;
void init_sArray(sArray *a, size_t initialSize);
void insert_sArray(sArray *a, char* element); 

typedef struct {
  int* array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} iArray;
void init_iArray(iArray *a, size_t initialSize);
void insert_iArray(iArray *a, int element); 

void free_dArray(dArray *a);
void free_sArray(sArray *a);
void free_iArray(iArray *a);
```

c file:

```
void init_dArray(dArray *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = (double *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(double));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}

void init_sArray(sArray *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = (char**)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char*));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}

void init_iArray(iArray *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}

void insert_dArray(dArray *a, double element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size = (a->size*3)/2+8;
    a->array = (double *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(double));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void insert_sArray(sArray *a, char* element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size = (a->size*3)/2+8;
    a->array = (char**)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(char*));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void insert_iArray(iArray *a, int element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size = (a->size*3)/2+8;
    a->array = (int*)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void free_dArray(dArray *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}

void free_sArray(sArray *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}

void free_iArray(iArray *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}
```

main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        iArray a;
        init_iArray(&a,5);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                insert_iArray(&a, i+1);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                printf("%d\n", a.array[i]);
        free_iArray(&a);
        exit(0);
}
```

Is there a way to reduce the code size, with or without polymorphism?

Comment: Note that questions about improving the quality or efficiency of working code are more appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you worried about the number of lines of code, the number of bytes in your source file, or the number of bytes in your compiled binary?

Comment: You might be able to eliminate some parts of redundant code when using only a single struct with a `type` field and an embedded `union` for all possible types

Comment: @ChristianGibbons well, I can live with it, but I don't like the presence of dubbing code.

Comment: First, you can abstract out capacity checking (they are the same for all the three types). Next, you can actually use a single procedure for all the three cases, passing it the inserted value as a type-erased combination of `void *` and element size. Third, by exploiting this approach beyond reasonable, you can use the same struct type for every array type. It would be a kind of polymorphism, more like a run-time implementation of templates.

Comment: Macro can be your friend on this.

Comment: Research `_Generic` as a way to call `int_...`, `insert_...` without having to specify the type  in the function name.

Comment: Don't cast the result returned by `malloc()` - it is unnecessary, and can also mask the serious error of a missing prototype.

Comment: @chux Wouldn't that be `C`'s version of polymorphism, which is not what OP is looking for?  I think they would rather not write the various functions themselves, rather than not need to specify which of the functions to call.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons OP post's had "is there a way to reduce the code size, with or without polymorphism?" so I did not see _polymorphism_ as the dominate issue.

Comment: @chux Fair enough.  When I asked for clarification, OP mentioned not "dubbing" (repeating?) code, so I think the intention is to write one function that works for all.  The question could have been a bit clearer on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply **abstract away the type of the elements**. All your array needs to know is how big those elements are. You can go the full way of allowing the user to supply a copy constructor and destructor via function pointers, or you can limit the scope of your array to `memcpy()` movable types.

#### Providing an array for plain data elements

You simply add the size of the elements as a parameter to your array `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
  char *array;
  size_t elementSize;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;

void Array_init(Array *a, size_t elementSize, size_t initialSize);
void Array_insert(Array *a, const void* element);
const void* Array_at(Array *a, size_t index);
void Array_destruct(Array *a);
```

All indexing into the array simply multiplies the index with the given element size to index the internal `char` array. The internal `char` pointers are implicitly converted to the `void` pointers of the interface, which in turn are implicitly converted to `double` pointers, or whatever other type you plug into this array.

This works great *as long as the elements are trivially copyable*. If you elements need to manage memory themselves, you need the following approach:

#### Providing an array for complex data elements

If you objects need to do custom stuff when they are copied, you need to provide a means for the user to supply the necessary behavior. That is done via function pointers:

```
typedef void (*Array_callback_copy_construct)(void* this, const void* original);
typedef void (*Array_callback_destruct)(void* this);
typedef struct {
  char *array;
  size_t elementSize;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
  Array_callback_copy_construct copy_construct;
  Array_callback_destruct destruct;
} Array;

void Array_init(Array *a, size_t elementSize, size_t initialSize, Array_callback_copy_construct copy_construct, Array_callback_destruct destruct);
void Array_insert(Array *a, const void* element);
const void* Array_at(Array *a, size_t index);
void Array_destruct(Array *a);
```

The `Array_insert()` and `Array_destruct()` methods now simply use the user provided callback functions to copy and destroy the elements of the array.

More advanced versions might also use a move constructor callback, and/or a (move) assignment callback. Copy construction + destruction is the minimal set you need, better performance may be achieved with the more advanced callbacks.

---

The first method is simple enough to be useful in a wide variety of applications, and I would not hesitate to use it. However, **the catch of the use of `memcpy()` must be clearly documented**.

The second method works where the first method fails, but it's generally much more hassle than it's worth. Avoid it unless you figure that it's really the only solution.

Comment: [Object-oriented Programming with ANSI C (Chapter 2)](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) provides a careful introduction to an approach using C. Noteworthy is the position of the object size being the first member within the struct allowing a clever approach to object allocation and destruction. Not directly on point, but a good reference on the topic.